# two count in select statment using DQL / Doctrine

Tags: jquery, sql, symfony, count, doctrine-orm

I have two tables Product and comment,

I am looking to make a query with DQL / using symfony.

Normally i can do something like that :

```
// Get number of comment not visited per product
Select count (p.id) from Product p, Comment c where P.id = c.p_id and c.status = 0;

// Get number of comment read visited per product
Select count (p.id) from Product p, Comment c where P.id = c.p_id and c.status = 1;
```

But, while im using pagination bundle i need to pass just one query in parameter (like i am also using a Filter bundle also need to have just one query so he can apply the filter on it).

Any idea!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14294335/875519

Adapted to your case, this should do the trick :

```
$this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('
    SELECT COUNT(p1) AS p1, COUNT(p2) AS p2
    FROM YourBundle:Product p1, YourBundle:Product p2, YourBundle:Comment c1, YourBundle:Comment c2
    WHERE p1.id = c1.p_id AND c1.status = 0
    AND p2.id = c2.p_id AND c2.status = 1
');
```